# how can I get from mol% to percent by volume?

Tags: concentration

I have mol% of a gas sample I also have temp and  pressure when the sample was taken.  How do I get % by volume? (L) [image: data]

Comment: assume ideal gas behavior and then mole % = volume %. // Remember that one mole of an ideal gas occupies 22.71 liters per mole at 0 °C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mol% and % by volume should be the same, assuming ideal gas behavior. For example, a sample containing 11.2 liters (1/2 mole) of hydrogen and 11.2 liters (1/2 mole) of methane should be 50 mol% hydrogen and 50 mol% methane, as well as 50% hydrogen by volume and 50% methane by volume. Note that by weight, the percentages of the components are no longer 50-50.